# Typecasting char to long

Tags: c++, c

Say I have a variable, *a*

```
char a = 0x01;
```

and I want to cast this to a long, as in

```
long b;
b = (long)a;
```

Will the upper 3 bytes in *b* be guaranteed to be 0? With my setup they are 0, but I'm not sure if this is compiler-dependent.

Comment: First, you don't need the cast; that's a **standard conversion**. Second, use initialization instead of creating an uninitialized variable and then assigning to it. `long b = a;`.

Comment: The "upper" or "lower" is a wong term, as will depend on endianness. But yes, the 3 *most significant* bytes will be 0.

Comment: Previous comments apply but beware: if the `char` type is signed on your platform, the `long` variable will be sign extended. Example: `char a = 0x90; long b = a;` -> the content of `b` will probably not be what you expect.

Comment: `long` can easily have 8 bytes, btw.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `b` is guaranteed to have the value `0x1` after this assignment even without the cast. The assignment operator in c++ is generally semantic or value driven, it will copy the value or state, rather than preform bit wise copy (even if the two are sometimes equivalent, such as for trivial types).

In some cases, specially because of operator overloading, this may not be the case. Developers are very strongly encouraged to keep to this concept when they design new types, but a careless programmer could overload the assignment operator for non-fundamental types to do anything he/she wants.

Comment: "b is guaranteed to represent the value 0" !? I think not. Whatever "represent" means here.

Answer (score 2):

As a long can represent all values for a char (be it signed or unsigned) the conversion is guaranteed to not change the value.

If you initially have a positive value, because either char is signed in you architecture or because the char values is between 0 and 127 (assuming 8 bit characters), the resulting long is guaranteed to be positive and less that 256. So in an architecture where long is 4 bytes large, the 3 high order bytes are guaranteed to be 0.

If char is signed and if the initial value is negative, things will be different! The value will be unchanged and will still be negative. In a common 2'complement architecture, the 3 high order bits will be 0xFF

Answer (score 0):

The answer already given is right, but I thought I'd add that for C++, it is recommended to use one of the C++-specific casting notations, to make it abundantly clear what you are doing. Here, you would use:

```
long b;
b = static_cast<long>(a);
```

This makes it very clear what you are doing (a cast whereby how the cast is performed is calculated at compile time to a `long`), and you know that the "right" sort of cast will be performed.

Comment: It's recommended to use a C++-style cast rather than a C-style cast. But in this case, it's not recommended to use any kind of cast, since the conversion will be done implicitly.

Comment: Surely it's better to always be explicit about things like this?

Comment: Not really. Explicit conversions can override compile-time checks. Implicit conversions are more restricted and tend to be safer. With a cast, a reader has to verify that the target type is correct (for example `b = static_cast<int>(a);` would  compile without complaint).

Answer (score 0):

```
char a = 0x01;

long b;
b = (long)a;
```

C and C++ are two different (but closely related) languages. Their rules happen to be the same in this case.

The cast (not "typecast") is not necessary.  The assignment could, and probably should, be written as:

```
b = a;
```

which causes an implicit conversion from `char` to `long`. Since the value being converted is within the representable range of type `long`, the result of the conversion is `1`. The result of the conversion is specified in terms of *values*, not *representations*.

The representation of the value `1` in type `long` *probably* has a `1` in the low-order bit, and `0`s in all the other bits. (And the position of the low-order bit can vary; some systems are *big-endian*, some are *little-endian*, and there are other possibilities.)

There is no guarantee that type `long` even has three high-order bytes. Type `long` is at least 32 bits wide, but a byte can be wider than 8 bits. It's even possible that there are values of type `char` that exceed `LONG_MAX` (if plain `char` is signed and `long` is 1 byte, which implies `CHAR_BIT >= 32`).

It's also possible that the representation of type `long` includes *padding bits*, bits that do not contribute to the value. It's guaranteed that the sign bit is `0`, the low-order value bit is `1`, and all other value bits are `0`, but if there are padding bits their values are not guaranteed. (Some combinations of padding bits can result in a *trap representation* that does not represent any value, but that can't happen in this particular case.)

Most of these exotic possibilities are very unlikely to occur in real life. C implementations for some DSPs do have bytes wider than 8 bits, but  any system you're using almost certainly has 8-bit bytes.

The point is that the result of the conversion is defined in terms of values, not representations, and 99% of the time that's all you need to care about. If you write:

```
char a = 1; /* same as 0x01 */
long b = a;
printf("b = %ld\n", b);
```

it will print `b = 1`, even if you're using some exotic system where the value `1` is represented strangely.

Comment: If char is signed CHAR_MAX cannot be greater than LONG_MAX. This is only possible if char is unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

`b`  will be 1; this is always, compiler and endianness-independent, true. Additionally, the following expressions will be true:

```
b == 1
b == 01
b == 0x1
b == 0x00000001
b == 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

The right hand side in all cases is an `int` constant with the value 1; not more, not less. Note that the zeroes do not represent bytes in memory (an `int` most likely does not have the number of bytes the last expression appears to suggest). The hexadecimal notation is just another way to write down a 1, exactly like `1`.

In particular, we don't know where in memory the byte with the value 1 is located, because that is architecture dependent. It may be the one at the address of the int, or it may be the other end, or even in between.

Now comes the sweet thing: **C does not care how the memory in an `int`  is laid out.** None of the ways to write an integer constant is architecture dependent. That seems self-understood with decimal constants — did we expect that the meaning of `int i = 1` is architecture dependent? Certainly not. Nor is `int i = 0x00000001;`. The same is true for the bit shift operators: `<<` shifts towards more significant bits, `>>`  towards less significant bits. The digits in (decimal or hexadecimal) integer constants are ordered so that the most significant digits are on the left side, aligning with the "direction" indicated by the arrow-like bit shift operators. That may or may not reflect your machine's `int`  representation; on a PC it does not.

Bottom line: If you use the standard C (or C++) means to test the "upper 3 bytes", you are home free, and the following is always true, independent of the implementation or architecture:

```
char a = 0x01;
long b = a;

(b & 0x11)       == 1 // least significant byte is 1
(b & 0x00000011) == 1 // exactly the same as above
(b & 0x11111100) == 0 // more significant three bytes are all 0
```

It's possible that your `long`  has more bits, but that is implementation dependent. How many more there are: they are all zero, save for the least significant one.